# Magento 2 I want to update cart quantity using ajax, how can I do this?

Tags: magento2

I have a controller, from where I can send cart quantity. And I used ajax call to fetch data

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/mycart/cartcount",
        type: "POST",
        data: "",
        success: function (res) {
            jQuery(".cart_qty").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

My question is, how can I get cart quantity in my controller?

Comment: As per as,your code, you do not send any parameters controller then how you get Cart Qty and  Cart Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply update the qty field in the quote_item table because there is lots of constrains that has.

1. Validate requested qty exist or not?
2. Is the product is **In-Stock** or not?
3. Is the product enabled or not and so?

and yes you can update the quantity field in quote table.

Try this, add this in your controller and you need to get **item_id** and **qty** to update the specific field.

```
<?php                                                                 
 namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;                                
 class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action                      
 {
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quote,
    array $data = []
  ) {
    $this->quoteRepository = $quote;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
 }
 public function execute()
 {
    $item_id = '6';
    $qty = '10';
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getById($item_id);
    foreach ($quote->getItems() as $quoteItem) {
        $quoteItem->setQty($qty);
    }
    $quote->save();
    return true;
 }}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Welcome mate :)